# EF 6.2, WPF - Get data from database preview results - doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have problem with EF 6.2 and WPF application.
When I try get data from DB (any collection) receives a message on Results View:

> Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable

when I expand next level message

> The function evaluation requires all threads to run

when I click refresh icon message it's changing

> Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

Image:
[image]

When I add `.ToList()` at the end of query everything's working fine I can view the results of my query. My code working OK but when i debbunging I can't show my result - this is very useful.

I do not want to add `.ToList()` for each my query because is part of big query.

Comment: Is [any of this helpful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eliofek/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run/)?

Comment: It's working when I add variable to "Add watch" the icon in question will appear, but this not working on demand (my screenshot) - why? In another solution where I have dbml everything works fine (LinqToSQL)

Comment: I solved my problem, I make downgraded `EF 6.2.0` to `EF 6.1.3` and everything returned to normal. Does anyone know why?